# Не работает регулярное выражение из переменной в python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, переменные

Почему-то так работает

```
result = re.search(r'(6)', u_values)
```

А так нет

```
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
day_today = current_datetime.day
day_today = str(day_today)
str_date = f"""r'({day_today})'"""

result = re.search(str_date, u_values)
```

Второй день бьюсь. Здесь находил варианты, тоже не срабатывают. Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то нужно заменить это

```
str_date = f"""r'({day_today})'"""
```

на это

```
str_date = fr'({day_today})'
```

Хотя не очень понятно, зачем вам здесь вообще raw-строки, если у вас в этой строке нет никаких спецсимволов.

Comment: Да! Спасибо огромное! Спецсимволы убрал для упрощения теста. Уже заработало и со спецсимволом. Плюсы от меня пока не видны, но учитываются :)

Answer (score 0):

Неверно составлен паттерн в `str_date`. И лишних нагромождений много.

Ошибка в следующей строке. Вы встраиваете модификатор `r` в саму строку. Плюс к этому за зря используете тройные кавычке и вообще эта строка бессмысленна для задачи.

```
str_date = f"""r'({day_today})'"""
# "r'(6)'"
```

Вы можете сократить четыре строки преобразований в одну

```
string = 'abc 6 cba 7'
day = str(datetime.now().day)
result = re.search(day, string)
```

И в целом использование регулярных выражений под вопросом. Если вам нужно проверить наличие в строке числа текущего дня, то используйте, например, `in`.

```
if day in string:
    print('Есть')
```